# Voltage regulation with a constant power

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter

I have a 12 V supply which has a 200 mA current. How can I get an output voltage of 5 V with an output current of 450 mA from the given supply so that the input and output powers are almost equal considering the conversion losses?

Comment: Please use search term "buck converter."

Comment: Or use a web search with the search terms "DC-DC converter", or "switch mode power supply". There are answers on this site which answer your question, but a web search will likely turn up ready made products as well as specialised components and circuits. That level of power efficiency will be hard though.

Answer (score 2):

Use a very efficient buck converter.

**Power In** = 12V*0.2A = 2.4W

**Power Out** = 5V*0.45A = 2.25W

**Efficiency** = 2.25W/2.4W = 0.9375

So, ~94% efficiency is required.

A very common [LM2596](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2596.pdf) won't reach your requirements but gets close.

Some regulators such as [MAX17502](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX17502.pdf) claim values that make your needs look viable:

[image]

If you can relax your requirements down to 85%~ you will get many more options. Or, if you can determine how long max load will be required vs how long your 12V PSU can tolerate overcurrent you may get away with it.

Comment: Thank you for responding, 85 % efficiency will be perfect,what are the other options that I can prefer.